# Program to make a binary tree out of a text file

Tags: java, tree, time-complexity, binary-tree

I need to make a Binary Tree out of txt file. Every line describes one node: X Y - where X is a char value and Y is a string which describes a direction. For example:
C RRL - node has a value 'C' and is located going from the root right(R), right(R), left

The output must be the last alphabetic word created from the words of the tree. The program can't use Collections or any other 'ready' Java solutions (streams etc.). Also it must have an average time complexity of O(nlogn) and memory complexity O(n).

Example:
**Input** 
G RR 
 A 
 C L 
 F LLR 
 X LLL 
 F R 
 X RL 
 H LL 
**Output** 
XHCA

I currently have the code that can construct a tree but only if the Nodes are in order from the root. It can't like "imagine" going after a root it doesn't exist. So only the beginning of the tree is correct.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("fileInput.txt");
        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                if(line.length()==1) {
                    bt.direction = "";
                }
                else
                    bt.direction = line.substring(2);
                bt.add(line.charAt(0));
            }
        }
    }

    static class BinaryTree {
        Node root;
        String direction;

        public void add(char letter){
            if(direction.isBlank())
                root = new Node(letter);
            else
                root = addRecursive(root, letter, 0);
        }
        private Node addRecursive(Node current, char letter, int j) {
            if (current == null) {
                    return new Node(letter);
                }
            if(j < direction.length()){
                if(direction.charAt(j)=='L'){
                        current.left = addRecursive(current.left, letter, ++j);
                    }
                else if (direction.charAt(j)=='R') {
                        current.right = addRecursive(current.right, letter, ++j);
                    }
                }
            return current;
        }

        }
    }

    static class Node {
        char letter;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node(char letter) {
            this.letter = letter;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the output starts with `X` not `H`?

Comment: It starts with X, because we're looking for the last alphabetic word. As X lies at the most left (LLL), we start with that

Answer (score 0):

You can read all values in a collection, then sort it by direction length, then loop through it and build a tree.

First read

```
G RR
A
C L
F LLR
X LLL
F R
X RL
H LL
```

Then sort by ***Y*** length

```
A
C L
F R
X RL
H LL
G RR
F LLR
X LLL
```

then build your tree, or analyze last nodes with some algorythm to put them in a correct order.

Comment: Soryy, had to add that I can't use collections :(

Comment: What about an Array?

Comment: Yeah I can use an Array but I can't think of a solution to fill it without knowing the size of a file.

Comment: You can check the file size first. Or you can create an Array of length 10 for example, and if there is more than 10 lines, you would create new array of length 10*2, put here all the values from the previous array and continue filling it from position 10. If there is more than 20 lines, you create new array of size 20*2, transfer here all data from the previous one and continue , ......... .
But you should count how many lines lines you read in separate variable  in that case.

Comment: Yeah this could work but I think it will exceed the complexity unfortunately :/